# raw_input should accept only single character

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

I am using below code.But instead of accepting a single character its allowing user to put more than a single character.

How can I fix that?

```
guess = raw_input(':')
guessInLower = guess.lower()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following will continuously prompt the user for input until they enter exactly one character.

```
userInput = ''
while len(userInput) != 1:
    userInput = raw_input(':')
guessInLower = userInput.lower()
```

This does the same, but also informs them of the one character limit before prompting again for input

```
while True:
    userInput = raw_input(':')
    if len(userInput) == 1:
        break
    print 'Please enter only one character'
guessInLower = userInput.lower()
```

It looks like you are expecting only letters. If that is the case you can expand this further to require that:

```
import string

while True:
    userInput = raw_input(':')
    if len(userInput) == 1:
        if userInput in string.letters:
            break
        print 'Please enter only letters'
    else:
        print 'Please enter only one character'
guessInLower = userInput.lower()
```

Comment: If you want this to work without pressing enter, one simple solution is to use [sshkeyboard](https://sshkeyboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It requires less coding, and it is a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 4):

By default python uses line-buffered input, which means that the `raw_input()` call will not return until the user hits enter. If you want to turn off the line buffering, you may have to look at OS-specific things you can do. [You can find a recipe demonstrating this here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892-getch-like-unbuffered-character-reading-from-stdin/).

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2.7.x,

```
guess = raw_input(': ')[0].lower()
```

For Python 3.x

```
guess = input (': ')[0].lower()
```

in both cases, the first character from the terminal raw input string (no need for using `''`) will be lowered and passed by to the variable `guess`.

Comment: smart trick Matt :)